# I am unable to add a css link, hover or active state on the 'create account' of my html

Tags: css, html

I am learning to do a bit of css but I have ran into a snag. I am unable to add a css link, hover or active state on the 'create account' of my html. I am using the `<p>` tag to do the styles and positioning. The link works fine but I can't add styles? Any help correcting the html will be welcome

```
<p>
  Join with us 
  <span class="fontawesome-arrow-right">
    <a href="http:the link works"> Create account</a>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the code and CSS that you're trying to use?

Comment: are you using font-awsome?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic CSS code for what you are trying to do:

```
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
</style>
```

You can read more at [CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Cheers !!